# How to get a point coordinate on a SkinnedMaterial for the human demo of three.js?

Tags: three.js

For the human demo http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_human , I wonder how to get a point on the skin of the human. For example when I click some place on the human body, what's the coordinate of that place?

I tried using the raycaster to get that but in vain.The code is like this:

```
  var projector;
  init() {
    // Others
    // ...

    projector = new THREE.Projector();
    renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
  }

  function onMouseUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
                   ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
                   - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
                   0.5
                 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    var intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects( character.root.children );

    if (intersections.length > 0) {
      debugger;
      // ...
    }

  }
```

But the `intersections` is always empty.

Three.js is r67

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I find that it's just because the human animation. It works if I comment the animation out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to three.js, and i've also tried to draw plots on the human. I manage to do it, but it's not on the "visible" body. In fact, you should first use the intersect method with the recursive arg :

```
var intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );
```

Thus, you 'll be able to interact with the objects composing the body, but they are not positioned under the "skin". It seems to be that they have been "moved", because *you can interact with them if you aim in front of the feet of the body*. Unfortunately, I don't know for the moment why, and how to interact with their "visible representation".